# How can I insert a cross-reference to a figure in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

Similar to the [cross-reference feature of Word](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gHqsqFNZy0), how can I insert a cross-reference to a figure in Google Docs?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a Figure?   I cannot see that as something that can be inserted in Docs.    I was thinking that perhaps you meant something that was labelled (eg "Figure 10") with a Caption (as per Word), but cannot see thing a option to do that.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ Indeed I was looking for an in-built feature insert an automatic label to a given figure or image. Sadly this essential feature does not exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With my new Docs add-on, [Cross Reference](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/cross_reference/269114033347).

It's still in its infancy, but I will be adding more features and fixing some bugs shortly.

Answer (score 15):

## Short answer

At this time Google Docs doesn't have the cross-reference feature.

## Explanation

The above is based on my personal experience with Google Docs and that there *is nothing relevant to cross-reference features* on the official documentation. To find the official documentation, go the link on the references section.

## Workarounds

- Use Google Apps Script. For an overview of using it to extend Google Docs see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs
- Use an add-on. To search for available add-ons on the Docs menu click on Add-ons > Get add-ons

## References

[Google Docs editors Help](http://support.google.com/docs)

Answer (score 13):

I think the most similar way to achieve this is to create a bookmark and reference it whenever need it.

- Insert bookmark before Table 1.

  Bookmark can be inserted from menu Insert > Bookmark
- Go to the place where you want to refer Table 1
- Type "Table 1", and select it to insert a link
- Collapse Bookmark in the link dialog and select Table 1

This is not ideal, after all you have to type "Table 1" twice. But it does allow user to navigate within the document. Therefore somehow similar to cross reference.

Comment: Interesting workaround. Thank you Douglas! However, I would still have to change Table 1 to a different numbering if I insert a table before it, correct?

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't give you auto numbering. But I assume you can use something more symbolic, like "Table - World Population", to avoid having to change the numbering.

Comment: Yes possibly. Depending, however, on the required citation style.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because the whole point of a reference is to have the numbers generated automatically, should the document change in future.

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer:** This is the official account of Docx2LaTeX

We have just launched a Google Docs-add on which combines the power of LaTeX and ease of Google Docs and cross-referencing too.

Here are the features provided by Docx2LaTeX add-On

1. Write **LaTeX code** snippets inside Google Docs with **syntax
   highlighting**.
2. **Add captions** to figures and tables.
3. **Cross-refer** figures,tables and equations.
4. **Auto update** captions and references when a new figure or a table is inserted.
5. View LaTeX compiled to **PDF in real-time**.
6. **Automatic** LaTeX source **code generation** and downloading.

**Add-On Link:**
[Docx2LaTeX Google Docs Add-on](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/docx2latex/415272416461)

**Watch Demo:**
[Short Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBVqgzbImug)

[image]

Comment: This seems to be really powerful, wow!

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want to add a link to chapter 10 in table of contents (TOC).

**Step 1** . Go to chapter 10. Select title, Select **Insert** option in menu. Insert **bookmark**.

**Step 2**. Go to table of contents page. Select text referring to chapter 10. From the menu, select **Insert**. Insert **Link**. Then select **Bookmarks** from the new menu that appears. Selcet bookmark specific to chapter 10. Done!

You can also edit the link text.

You can apply similar method to cross-reference images.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a new feature but you can now add a link to a heading (right click pick *link* then click *heading* and scroll down to the relevant one)

Not sure it works exactly equivalent to Word's feature but it's something.