# Google Docs mathematics equations reference numbers

Tags: google-docs

I am creating a document with multiple equations and I want to reference these equations in later parts of the document. Is there any easy way to do this in Google Docs, preferable automatically?

Comment: Probably not unless there's an add-on for that. Many people would use LaTeX for this purpose.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80194/how-can-i-insert-a-cross-reference-to-a-figure-in-google-docs

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarks in Docs allow you to link to any position in a doc.
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893